# How to do a GET request on PHP using CURL

Tags: php, curl, get, http-get

I have a simple GET request that I am trying to make and get the results back. I have tried it in Postman without any headers or body and it works just fine. I have even put it in my browser and it returns a good result. But, when I do it in PHP I am not getting anything. This is what my code looks like. What am I doing wrong?

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://********/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/kerberosLogin');
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, '20');

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);

        echo $resp;
```

Comment: you're just assuming nothing failed. curl_exec returns boolean false on failure, which would echo out as a zero-length string. try `if ($resp === false) { die(curl_error($curl)); }`

Comment: I am getting an echo back of nothing and I am expecting a simple JSON response back.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` to the end there and see if you get anything. Also, why are you passing the timeout as a string?

Comment: I get " string(0) "" " from the dump. I have tried it with the timeout as a number, which also didn't work (I saw to put it as a string somewhere online, it didnt make sense to me either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this header to send header like browser to server :

```
$curl = curl_init('http://********/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/kerberosLogin');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, '20');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.6',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:www.********.tld ', // for example : www.google.com
    'Referer: http://********/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/kerberosLogin',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Although, I now get this error: HTTP/1.0 302 Found Location: https://********/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/kerberosLogin Server: BigIP Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 0

Comment: 301 error means "Moved Permanently" , you should redirect to return location from response header [location : http://redirec-location.com/path/] - send curl request to new location - to see response header just enable tracking [comment end of the this line]